# how to test relative square area

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a minesweeper minigame, and I'm using NoAI chickens to represent mines, and armorstands to represent everything else. I want to increase the armorstands' scoreboard value by one for each adjacent chicken (diagonally or cardinally). I've figured out that it would be easiest to use an execute command from the chickens, but the problem is that `@e[type=ArmorStand,r=1]` doesn't get the diagonals, and `@e[type=ArmorStand,r=2]` gets armorstands two spaces away. Any ideas?

Comment: Does `r=1.5` work?

Comment: When did Minecraft add scripting? Or is this a mod?

Comment: @mpen   I'm using command blocks. You can get them with `/give <username> minecraft:command_block`

Comment: If you can space the chickens 1 block apart than you could test for those within a radius of 3

Comment: @AccioBooks Target selectors only allow integer data types. Floats and doubles do not work, so `1.5` will probably fail parsing, or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution myself. It involves using the relative coordinates in the `/execute` command. The command is:

```
/execute @e[type=Chicken] ~-1 ~ ~-1 scoreboard players add @e[type=ArmorStand,dx=2,dz=2] mine 1
```